# R, Sweave: How to pass file encoding to patchDVI::SweavePDF?

Tags: r, sweave

I have a master file `master.tex` containing the preamble and which inputs (via
`\input{chapter01}`, `\input{chapter02}`, ...) chapters. The chapters are .Rnw
files. My goal is to use patchDVI::SweavePDF to compile the chapters (say,
`chapter.Rnw`) individually (each chapter starts with sourcing Sweave preliminary
settings but [of course] does not have a preamble). When I execute

```
Rscript -e "patchDVI::SweavePDF('chapter.Rnw')
```

I obtain

```
Error: ‘chapter.Rnw’ is not ASCII and does not declare an encoding
```

Normally one uses `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to solve this problem. However, I
can't put this into chapter.Rnw since it is only allowed in the preamble, so in
master.tex. But there it has no effect. The question is how to solve this.

I found [this](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Sweave-UFT8-problem-td4558225.html) but I couldn't figure out how to adjust it to make it work with `patchDVI::SweavePDF`.

Answer (score 0):

I just now ran into this. For me it was a copy and pasted hyphen (-) that was the issue. When I pulled the text from another copy of my chapter it pasted in as a special character for some reason. I went through and replaced them by just typing - again in my code editor (using VSCode, but also works on Kate and Vim in the terminal).

Not a solution to the issue, but a workaround at the least. Hopefully this helps someone since the post is quite old now.